# Is there a condition such that if $f$ had this condition, $f(J)$ would be an open interval ( necessarily )?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is a continuous function defined on the interval $I$ and $J$ is an open interval such that $J \subseteq I$.

We know that $f(J)$ is an interval but not necessarily an open interval.

Is there a condition such that if $f$ had this condition,  $f(J)$ would be an open interval ( necessarily )?

I have no clue ... nothing to start with ...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The necessary (and sufficient, too) condition is:
>
> $f$ restricted to $J$ has *no global extreme*.

Comment: Can you please prove that ?

Comment: If *f* restricted to *J* has a global extreme, all points from *f(J)* are less than or equal (for maximum; for minimum it is similar) to its value, and this value belongs to *f(J)* - so *f(J)* is (semi-) closed interval. (continue...)

Comment: If *f(J)* is *not an open* interval - but still by the assignment it *is* interval - at least one end point of the interval *f(J)* behaves to it - and it is the global extreme of *f* restricted to *J*.

Answer (score 0):

One condition (along with  continuity) to guarantee that would be that $f$ is (strictly) increasing on $I.$ [or strictly decreasing]. On the other hand, if $f$ is allowed to be increasing and decreasing on various parts of $I,$ examples of non-open images could be constructed.